# Call to a member function where() on array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, eloquent

I have the following MySQL routine stored procedure "Sel_All_Observation_SP" :-

```
    BEGIN
    SELECT Observations_TBL.observation_id, Observations_TBL.number, Observations_TBL.date, Observations_TBL.status, Observations_TBL.content, Observations_TBL.recommendation, Observations_TBL.remark, Users_TBL.User_name, Type_Name_TBL.Type_Name, Supervisors_TBL.supervisor_name
    FROM ((Observations_TBL INNER JOIN Supervisors_TBL ON (Supervisors_TBL.supervisor_id = Observations_TBL.supervisor_id) AND (Observations_TBL.supervisor_id = Supervisors_TBL.supervisor_id)) INNER JOIN Type_Name_TBL ON (Observations_TBL.Type_Name_ID = Type_Name_TBL.Type_Name_ID) AND (Observations_TBL.Type_Name_ID = Type_Name_TBL.Type_Name_ID)) INNER JOIN Users_TBL ON (Users_TBL.User_ID = Observations_TBL.user_id) AND (Observations_TBL.user_id = Users_TBL.User_ID);

END
```

I am calling the above procedure in laravel using laravel query builder:-

```
DB::select('call Sel_All_Observation_SP()')
```

The above is returning result as an array.

I am trying to use where statement in above query:-

```
$observations = DB::select('call Sel_All_Observation_SP()')->where('user_id',1);
```

It return error :-

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \
>   FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>
> Call to a member function where() on array

I even tried to convert from array to collection by the following :-

```
$observations = collect(DB::select('call Sel_All_Observation_SP()')->where('user_id',1)->get());
```

It return same error

Comment: what you got when die dump?
dd(DB::select('call Sel_All_Observation_SP()'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're not selecting a table, the `where` statement wouldn't work. As for the `collect`, code, try changing the syntax a little so it reads:

```
$observations = collect(DB::select('call Sel_All_Observation_SP()'))->where('user_id',1);
```

The above code puts the data from the stored procedure into a collection. You can then use the `where` function to filter the results. No need to add `->get()` at the end.